# Array Manipulation to achieve pattern (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays both are of variable length, I want to achieve a pattern, which I have already achieved but not satisfied with my solution. I believe there could be a better way to achieve the same.

```js
const logic = (outerArray, innerArray) => outerArray.map((outerVal, OuterIndex) => {
  return innerArray.map((innerVal, innerIndex) => {
    const currentSlideIndex = OuterIndex + 1;
    if (innerArray.length < 6 && innerIndex + 1 === currentSlideIndex) return true;
    if (innerArray.length === 6) {
      if (innerIndex < 4 && innerIndex + 1 === currentSlideIndex) return true;
      // return false if currentslide is greater than four and less than last two slides
      if (currentSlideIndex > 4 && currentSlideIndex < outerArray - 1 && innerIndex === 3) {
        return true;
      }
      if (innerIndex === 4 && currentSlideIndex === outerArray - 1) return true;
      if (innerIndex === 5 && currentSlideIndex === outerArray) return true;
    }

    return '';
  });
});
```

Expected results

1. if innerArray length is less than or equal to 6 it should return array of length as innerArray and also the output should look like

   logic([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])

   Expected output

   ```
   [
       [true, "", "", "", ""],
       ["", true, "", "", ""], 
       ["", "", true, "", ""], 
       ["", "", "", true, ""], 
       ["", "", "", "", true]
   ]
   ```
2. if outerArray length is greater than 6 then it should work same for 3 index and should return true for index 4 for all outerArray index and resume at last two index.

   logic([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6])

   Expected output

   ```
   [
       [true,"","","","",""],
       ["",true,"","","",""],
       ["","",true,"","",""],
       ["","","",true,"",""],
       ["","","",true,"",""],
       ["","","",true,"",""],
       ["","","",true,"",""],
       ["","","",true,"",""],
       ["","","","",true,""],
       ["","","","","",true]
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I would split your code into two functions. The first one would return the column index of each value of your outerArray like so:

```js
const getColumnIndexes = (array) => {
    // Get first 3 items
    let columnIndexes = array.slice(0, 3);
    // Get items in 4th column
    columnIndexes = columnIndexes.concat(array.slice(3, Math.max(4, array.length - 2)).map(() => 4));
    // Get last 2 items
    columnIndexes = columnIndexes.concat(array.slice(Math.max(4, array.length - 2), array.length).map((val, index) => 5 + index));
    return columnIndexes;
};
```

Then your `logic` function becomes really simple:

```js
const logic = outerArray => {
    const columnIndexes = getColumnIndexes(outerArray);
    return outerArray.map((val, lineIndex) => {
        return Array(Math.min(6, outerArray.length)).fill().map((_, i) => i === columnIndexes[lineIndex] - 1 ? true : "");
    });
};
```

If I understood properly, you don't actually need this innerArray anymore.

```
logic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

[
    [true, "", "", "", ""],
    ["", true, "", "", ""], 
    ["", "", true, "", ""], 
    ["", "", "", true, ""], 
    ["", "", "", "", true]
]

logic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

[
    [true,"","","","",""],
    ["",true,"","","",""],
    ["","",true,"","",""],
    ["","","",true,"",""],
    ["","","",true,"",""],
    ["","","",true,"",""],
    ["","","",true,"",""],
    ["","","",true,"",""],
    ["","","","",true,""],
    ["","","","","",true]
]
```